# Rails f.check_box hide/show JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble with hiding the default label on my checkboxes in my Rails form.  I have a custom label and no matter what I try I always get the column name displayed.  I am also trying to use this checkbox as not only a model submission but to trigger a div hide/show event, and I cant seem to get that working either.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Minor?:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.check_box :minor %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my hide/show js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('customers_minor');
  var details_div = document.getElementById('minor_details');
  checkbox.onchange = function() {
     if(this.checked) {
       details_div.style['display'] = 'block';
     } else {
       details_div.style['display'] = 'none';
     }
  };
</script>
```

EDIT/SOLUTION
I have figured out how to add the custom label by adding `do` to the label line.
`<%= f.check_box :minor do %>Custom Label<% end %>`

```
<label for="customer_minor">
    <input name="customer[minor]" type="hidden" value="0">
    <input id="customer_minor" name="customer[minor]" type="checkbox" value="1">
Custom Label
</label>
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us the generated HTML, too. Are you certain the `id` attribute is `customers_minor`? It might be different depending on what from builder gem you use.

Comment: I edited the post a bit you might want to check it out.

Comment: It should be `customer_minor` (singular) not `customers_minor` (plural).

Comment: Also, use `onclick`, not `onchange`, since this is a checkbox, not a textual field. The `onclick` event is the `onchange` equivalent of a checkbox.

Comment: is there a way to implement a smooth jquery scroll to the div after is becomes shown?

Comment: Open a different question for that. I don't use jQuery much, but I'd guess there *probably* is a way.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `id` attribute is actually `customer_minor`, not `customers_minor` (singular versus plural).

Also, the checkbox doesn't react on the `onchange` event because its value doesn't change. You should use the `onclick` event instead; this will also work for keyboard-triggered events (ie, using tab to focus and pressing space).

Answer (score -1):

The hide/show JS could be resolved like this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var checkbox    = document.getElementById('customer_minor');
var details_div = document.getElementById('minor_details');

checkbox.onchange = function() {
   if(this.checked) {
     details_div.style['display'] = 'block';
   } else {
     details_div.style['display'] = 'none';
   }
};
```

It looks like your `id` was incorrect (you can [see working JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6akqywcx/)).

--

You should also ensure you put your JS into the asset pipeline files -- `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` etc.

Comment: Perfect,  How could I implement a smooth scroll to the div as well?

Comment: That would be another question which I will answer if you provide a link!

Comment: I'm sorry but a link to what?